# Post article on all social media

Tags: javascript, php, html, share, social-networking

I have searched the Internet for 1 hour but I got nothing.

I developed a news portal site in PHP and now I want my user to **share the news article** with the respective title, thumbnail and content on **all social media networks** (ideally by clicking only in one button).

Comment: Hi do please give [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  a read.

Comment: and I need a million dollars, but without working for it, I can't expect / hope to even get close

Comment: @Epodax maybe the question is poorly written, but it has some relevance though, I'm not familiar with any method to share the page in all social networks at once (specially customized).

Comment: @Armfoot as I read the question, the OP wants us to provide the code for the different media share / like (etc) buttons, which isn't what SO does, even THEN, I know for a fact that both facebook, twitter and google+ (the major social sites?) have a guide and easy way to integrate this.

Comment: @Epodax I understand, but the OP is not necessarily asking for the code, he's just trying to find a website/tool/plugin that does this for him/her (similar to Sanjay's answer)... Even I would like to know if there's a thing like that already.

Comment: @Armfoot - Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Epodax In this case, I searched for a tool like that myself and I couldn't find one, so maybe it's not very prone to attract opinionated answers as it may seem... Either the tool provides a "shareall" option in one button, or it doesn't. Maybe this will make people think in developing something for that ;P

Answer (score 1):

Someone, you need to define "all" social media, do you want to include "P0rnshare" the great new social media app for sharing great p0rno videos, for example?

If you can't find a pre-made answer or the answers you get such as the details given by Sanjay, You should approach this by having a PHP/Ajax page to go through and take the data you wish to submit and apply it to each Social media outlet you want to use, so have a Twitter submission system and then a Facebook submission system, etc.

Edit: The above outline description would only work if the user was *currently logged in* to each of their respective social media profiles. Else each social media would require login validation. A single page system can use these login cookies to validate authentication for each social media site.

Comment: Martin, I guess when he mentions "all", he refers a predefined set of networks, an option that you may choose which to send from a list (like in [share this](http://www.sharethis.com/)) and when you'd click on a "share on all" button, it would send the data to all of those sequentially, without any other interaction from the user.

Comment: Hi @Armfoot - yes, my second paragraph addresses this, the OP or someone interested in this should write a page taking the chosen data and then applying it sequentially to the chosen destination sites, such as Twitter and then Facebook. This page shouldn't need other interactions as long as the user is logged in on their social media's, I *think* it can use cookies to validate the submission to each one.

Comment: My reference to PornShare was satirical, but does have the point that there are actually several dozen mainstream social media websites and only a very few are really, really big at the moment, does not mean that people do not want to use the others as well

Answer (score 0):

You can't share with single click on all social sites at once. There are lots of plug-ins that supporting such features.

1. [Add This](http://www.addthis.com/social-plugins/sharing-tools)
2. [Share This](http://www.sharethis.com/)

You just need to put their Javascript into your page.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: yes @sanjay i know that i can't share with single click on all social sites at once. is there a code to for all social share buttons ?

Comment: hi sanjay here is my share this button code for facebook <span class='st_facebook_hcount' st_url="http://example.in/client/single_media_news.php?pr_uni=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" st_title="<?php echo $row['title'];?>" st_image="http://example.in/upload_images/<?php echo $row['img_name'];?>" st_summary="<?php echo $row['description'];?>" displayText='Facebook' id="fb"></span>

Comment: but it does not shows the title, or the image of my single article which i have specified. do you tell me where i am doing wrong